# interpolate a string containing double quotes in a shell script

Tags: python, bash

I want to pass json string from python code to shell script in original format like;

```
json_val = check_input_file['Item']['mappings']['S']
print(json_val)
```

The output of above code is:

```
{
    "1": [
        "skipColumn"
    ],
    "2": [
        "firstname"
    ],
    "3": [
        "lastname"
    ],
    "4": [
        "email"
    ],
    "5": [
        "skipColumn"
    ],
    "6": [
        "ipaddress"
    ]
}
```

So now I am passing `json_val` to shell like:

```
init_script = '''#!/bin/bash 
       FOO="{0}"
       echo $FOO
        '''.format(json_val)
```

In FOO variable I get string without double quotes but I want it same as above.

I tried something like this

```
MAPPINGS=$(cat <<EOF
{"1":["skipColumn"],"2":["firstname"],"3":["lastname"],"4":["email"],"5":["skipColumn"],"6":["ipaddress"]}
EOF
)
```

But this is not what I want.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `json_val` for shell usage, otherwise double quotes will be dropped while the shell is performing quote removal.

It's also necessary to enclose `$FOO` in double quotes, otherwise you'd lose linebreaks in its content after the shell performed word splitting.

```
import shlex

init_script = '''
#!/bin/bash -
FOO={}
echo "$FOO"
'''.format(shlex.quote(json_val))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://ideone.com/aCzmWM)</sup>

Comment: Probably also highlight the double quotes around the argument to `echo`. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)